# thymeleaf html5 datepicker setting min date from variable not working

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

Im trying to set the an html datepicker to not allow dates before today to be picked.  For some reason it wont read it from a stored variable.

in controller:

```
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
model.addAttribute("now", now);
```

in html:

```
<input type="date" name="bookingDate" min="${now}"/>
```

I outputted "now" to the console while running to see its output and I got 2017-12-11 exactly as the min value of date asks for.  It doesnt set the datepicker.  I copy pasted the output from console directly into the html instead of ${now} and it worked.
I also formatted it as a string instead of a LocalDate just as a test.  Both outputs to console were the same but neither worked in html.
Am I missing something simple or is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use th:attr to add a new attribute.

For example -

```
th:attr="min=${now}"
```

Look [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-attribute-values) for the more detailed explanation.

Comment: oh. I feel silly.  Thanks for the quick reply!  I guess I was looking at the "type" and "name" fields with the "th" and didnt occur to me to add it on that field.

Comment: Well I actually didn't use th:attr.  Seeing your example though I remembered that I might need the th.  
So this worked:
<input type="date" name="bookingDate" th:min="${now}"/>

Answer (score 2):

@nirvair answer is correct. Just an additional info from my side

```
th:attr="min=${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
```